# How can I reverse this Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.2

I've got a successful match on:

```
/^\/?build\/(.+\.coffee|.+\.sass|.+\.erb)$/
```

Now I want to find all files under /build/ that DON'T match either of those extensions. I think I can do this with negative look-ahead but I can't seem to get it working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not use the proper control structure in your language, i.e. `unless` instead of `if`?

Comment: Agreed but the gem I'm using "Guard" expects regex for its matches. I could match on all files then discard them, that seems.. ugly.. though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you find all files under /build/ and DON'T match either of those extensions,you'd better use "?!" to except string,for example:

```
^\/?build\/(?:(?!\.coffee|\.sass|\.erb).)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extensions = [".coffee",".sass",".erb"]
Find.find(build_folder) do |file|
  next unless extensions.include?(File.extname(file))
end
```

Also, do you know of this?

```
if some_string =~ /some_regex/
  # matched regex
end

if some_string !~ /some_regex/
  # didn't match regex
end
```